# How cite a website with bibtex?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm trying to write this reference :

```
[2]: World Health Organisation, 2017. Vision impairment and blindness. 
     Fact Sheet N°282. http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs282/fr/. 
     Accessed: 2017-11-30
```

I tried with :

```
@misc{OMS,
    author = {World Health Organisation},
    year = {2017},
    title = {Vision impairment and blindness},
    subtitle = {Fact Sheet N°282},
    url = {http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs282/fr/},
    note = {Accessed = 2017-11-30} 
}
```

But it gives me : `[2] World Health Organisation. Vision impairment and blindness, 2017. Accessed = 2017-11-30.`

I don't have all information like the first like I show you. Can You help me please ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which bibliography style do you employ? And, which citation call-out style do you employ: numeric, author-year, or something else?

Comment: I use \bibliographystyle{plain} and a numeric call-out

Comment: If you can consider using `biblatex` it has  an `online` entry type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- The `plain` bibliography style doesn't know about a field called `subtitle`. Hence, combine the `title` and `subtitle` fields into a single `title` field.
- Unless you're using either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, the `°` character in `N°282` is going to give you grief. Change it to either `N\textsuperscript{o}282` or `No.~282`.
- The `plain` bibliography style doesn't know about a field called `url` either. (`plain` predates the World Wide Web. Really.) Hence, combine the `url` and `note` fields into a single `note` field. Do encase the URL string in a `\url{...}` wrapper; naturally, you should be loading the `url` package, preferably with the options `hyphens` and `spaces`. Also, please change "Accessed = 2017-11-30" to "Last accessed on 2017-11-30".
- Last but not least, do encase the `author` field in double, not single, curly braces. That way, the author is marked as a "corporate author", and the entry will get sorted under W instead of under O. (Without the extra pair of curly braces, BibTeX will parse the name as consisting of two given names ("World" and "Health") and one surname ("Organization"); that's why BibTeX would try to sort the entry under "O" for "Organization". Not what you'd want or expect, right?

In short, write the entry as follows:

```
@misc{OMS,
    author= {{World Health Organisation}},
    year  = {2017},
    title = {Vision impairment and blindness, {Fact Sheet N\textsuperscript{o}282}},
    note  = {\url{http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs282/fr/}, 
             Last accessed on 2017-11-30},
}
```

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{OMS,
    author= {{World Health Organisation}},
    year  = {2017},
    title = {Vision impairment and blindness, {Fact Sheet N\textsuperscript{o}282}},
    note  = {\url{http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs282/fr/}, 
             Last accessed on 2017-11-30},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{OMS}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response and for all explanation it helps me!